# How to keep the toggle content open even after page reload?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I use a jquery to toggle an `ul` when `li` is clicked. I happens as I expect. But as I have given a anchor `a` tag for `li` when the `li` is clicked It reloads and opens the `url` mentioned in the anchor tag. So the `ul` which was opened using `toggle` is getting closed automatically.

My jquery snippet is:

```
    <script>  
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
  $j('li.level1').click(function() { 
    $j('ul.level1:visible').hide();
    $j('ul.level1', this).toggle();
  });

});
</script>
```

My html is:

```
    <ul class="level0">
<li class="level1">
  <a href="#">Toggle</a>
  <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento_1.9.2.4/collection/shop-by-collection.html">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento_1.9.2.4/collection/shop-by-feature.html">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/magento_1.9.2.4/collection/shop-all.html">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="level1">
  <a href="#">Toggle</a>
  <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="level1">
  <a href="#">Toggle</a>
  <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Below is actually my phtml from where the html is generated:

```
    <ul class="level0">
<?php foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
 <li class="level1">
<a href= "<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($cat) ?>" >
  <?php echo $cat->getName() ?> 
  </a>
  <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>

                    <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li class="level2">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>

                <?php endif; ?>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I want to keep the `ul` of selected `li` to be kept open even when the page is reloaded or refreshed.

Comment: Consider adding your html or better, add a jsfiddle or snippet ;-D

Comment: @ShrameeSrivastav I have updated my question.

Comment: You can store menu state in a cookie or local storage to be sure it will be available after reload, then check this state on page load to restore menu status.

Comment: @mdameer How to use cookie in jquery? can you please help me do that in my above code?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...
This is an interesting question :-)

The idea behind the solution is to find `a` with `href` equal to current page url, then show it's parent `ul` on page load.

The downside is that you can't use relative urls like `about.html`, instead you need to use absolute urls `http://example.com/about.html` where `http://example.com` is url to your site ;)

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
  $j('li.level1').click(function() { 
    $j('ul.level1:visible').hide();
    $j('ul.level1', this).toggle();
  });
  $j( 'ul.level0 a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]' ).parents('ul.level1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level0">
<li class="level1">
  <a href="#">Toggle</a>
  <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="level1">
  <a href="#">Toggle</a>
  <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level2"><a href="?1">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="http://stacksnippets.net/js">Level2 This will be shown open because url matches ;-)</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="?3">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="level1">
  <a href="#">Toggle</a>
  <ul class="level1" style="display:none;">
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  <li class="level2"><a href="#">Level2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATED : Uses cookies to remeber the index of li clicked and open relevant after page load**

This new approach uses cookies to remember the index of list item clicked, then shows it after reload...

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
  $j('li.level1').click(function() {
    $j('ul.level1:visible').hide();
    $j('ul.level1', this).toggle();
    var i = $j(this).index('.level0 li.level1')
    document.cookie = "currentlyOpenUl=" + i;
  });

  var allcookies = document.cookie.split(';');

  // Now take key value pair out of this array
  for (var i = 0; i < allcookies.length; i++) {
    name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
    value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
    if ('currentlyOpenUl' == cookiearray[i].split('=')[0]) {
      $j('.level0 li.level1').eq(cookiearray[i].split('=')[1]).click();
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Sorry sir. Still the opened `ul` closes when the link is clicked or page is refreshed. Kindly help

Comment: Hmm... which exact html are you trying with...?

Comment: Need to know the url instead of `#` signs to determine the type of url...

Comment: Won't need full `html` just whole `ul.level0`

Comment: Sorry Ramya... But can you add rendered `html`, you can find it by viewing source... It's hard to know what your php functions do :)

Comment: Sir I have attached the rendered html structure in the above question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115297/discussion-between-ramya-and-shramee-srivastav).